# How to transfer files between Ubuntu machines?

Tags: server, files, home-server, transfer

I understand that this is a totally novice question but...

What is the best way for me to transfer files between two PC's? I have a laptop with Ubuntu Desktop (12.04) and a local server I'm setting up using Ubuntu Server. I'm used to windows environment where I might typically browse the network via Windows explorer and move files around. This might work for Ubuntu desktop, but what's the best way for Ubuntu server?

Do I need to create a user on the server, then SSH into the server from the laptop? Can I then use a move command to move my files back and forth? What do I need to look into?

Thanks.

Comment: if any of these answers "answered" your question please accept one of them :)

Comment: @blade19899 - To be honest, in the end I didn't end up using any of these solutions, think I used SCP or something - I forget. Marking your answer as correct since it's the closest thing to what I was actually after. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give [giver](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/giver-makes-transfer-of-files-easier-on-a-linux-network/) a try

> Giver Makes Transfer of Files Easier On A Linux Network By farshad on
>   Feb 14 2011
>
> Giver is a simple file sharing desktop application for Ubuntu Linux
>   users. It automatically detects other users running Giver on a network
>   and allows sending files and folders to them via simple drag and drop.
>   There is no need to learn about complex network file sharing
>   procedures. Anyone on the network can send files by dragging and
>   dropping a file or folder next to the icon and name of a computer user
>   visible on the main interface.
>
> After Giver is installed, it shows you other computers on the network
>   that have it installed as well, along with their computer name, IP and
>   picture (provided the user has set one using Gravatar).

[download giver](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/38690140/giver_0.1.8-6_all.deb)

The first issue with Giver is a missing .so file that prevents it from working. This can be fixed by installing libx11-dev (11.10/11.04/12.04)

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

For Ubuntu 11.10/12.04 besides the above issue, there's another issue that prevents Giver from working (it occurs for all applications that still use Mono runtime 2.0 instead of  To fix this, run the command below:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/giver.desktop
```

And under "Exec", replace "giver" with the following:

```
/usr/bin/mono --runtime=v4.0 /usr/lib/giver/Giver.exe
```

**Source**:

- [Get Giver To Work In Ubuntu 12.04 And 11.10 [Quick Tip] ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/get-giver-to-work-in-ubuntu-1110-and.html)

Comment: how do i share the files between machines after installing giver, I am not able to access one machines content from other machines.

Comment: U can try https://launchpad.net/nitroshare

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use scp command :

As you use cp command `cp ~/file/ /mnt/file1

You can use scp : `scp ~/file/ user@host:~/file1`

Then it will prompt for credentials .

Answer (score 4):

## [Video explanation](https://youtu.be/iuQkp3AKYKw)

It's very simple in Ubuntu 16.04. You can just use the "connect to server" button in files (nautilus). In the popup window you need to type an sftp string like this:

```
sftp://username@hostname.local/
```

where `username` is the username of the other machine, and `hostname` is the hostname of the other machine. Then you'll be prompted for a password and you're good to go.

*Note that you have to `sudo apt install openssh-server` on the remote machine.*

Answer (score 1):

Rsync is probably your best bet. It is an incremental file transmission protocol that allows you to keep folders in sync between machines, so it would be especially good for things like media.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier than that. If in the same local network, just right click on the folder you want to share and click sharing options. Then you get a menu which is self explanatory. That should work out of the box between two ubuntu machines.

Let me know!

Comment: This is a very simplistic answer. For details on how to actually get sharing to work, see [Setting up sharing between two Ubuntu machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156169/how-do-i-set-up-file-sharing-between-two-ubuntu-laptops-on-my-wireless-network/156222#156222).