# Share files - Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 - one network - password not accepted

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, windows-xp, file-sharing

I ask this question in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/485603/share-files-ubuntu-12-4-and-windows-7-one-network-password-not-accepted) but no one helps me. I hope to get more attention here.

I have three computers connected in one network by modem. I want to share files in this network in the most easy way (I have read about solutions using Samba).

So, I have three machines:

1. One with Windows 7
2. One with Windows XP
3. One with Ubuntu 12.04

and I have the following situation:

1. The windows PCs can share files between each other.
2. The windows PCs can see that Ubuntu's one is in the network
3. The PC with Ubuntu can see only the PC with Windows 7, but when I click on a folder it ask to enter the network password and it is not accepting it (I am 100% sure it's the correct one)

Is there to fix this situation a little bit - at least to enable the file sharing between the Ubuntu and Windows 7 PCs or I should choose a different approach (please advice).

Comment: Best to [pick one site or the other](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3536/12864) to post to.

Comment: yeah, file-sharing can be rather complicated, this might be worth a shot https://launchpad.net/nitroshare

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156169/how-do-i-set-up-file-sharing-between-two-ubuntu-laptops-on-my-wireless-network/156222#156222

Answer (score 1):

You will want to install samba and configure the workgroup as explained in the [Ubuntu 12.04 Samba help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html).  I have had some problems with passwords on Windows-Ubuntu shares, so you might want to consider doing this without password, but set the share as read only so your files cannot be modified or deleted remotely.

Answer (score 0):

If you install samba, you can share files Ubuntu as Windows. And if there isn't shared folder, you can't connect to the other computer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to disable the Windows 7 network password? I have managed to connect+transfer some files from a Windows 7 workstation to Ubuntu 12.10 64bit.

Like you said, I couldn't **see** Linux in the network from Windows 7, but was able to see the Windows PC from Linux and I also was able to access to `Windows shared files`. One more important thing: After I transfered files from Linux to Windows PC [read+write shared folder], the files transfered with success, but Windows were unable to open/read them.

I think its a **file-permission** issue. Your question is one year old, so hopefully it is still relevant to you, or someone else.