# How can I set up full access sharing on my network?

Tags: 12.04, networking, file-sharing

I want to setup a home network that grants full access to and from all machines in my home. All 4 of my machines are running Ubuntu 12.04. I tried setting up filesharing but have 2 problems with this: First, it does not grant me the complete access I desire and I have to share individual directories one by one. 
Secondly, after following the instructions here for quick file sharing setup: [How do I set up file sharing between two Ubuntu laptops on my wireless network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156169/how-do-i-set-up-file-sharing-between-two-ubuntu-laptops-on-my-wireless-network)
under "browse network" all machines show up, but when I try to to open them,  I see this: 
[image: opening]
Followed by this a few seconds later: 
[image]

I would appreciate any assistance I can get on his issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the smb.conf file for editing (`gksu gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf`) and look through the Share Definitions section, it seems to have all you need.

```
#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each 
# user's home director as \\server\username
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
   read only = no

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server. Un-comment the following parameter
# to make sure that only "username" can connect to \\server\username
# The following parameter makes sure that only "username" can connect
#
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S
```

Un-commpent means removing the `;` from the beginning of a line (don't remove the hash signs). Uncommenting stuff in the first two paragragraphs, and setting the home directory to be writable and browsable, the way I've done above should really be it.

Save and exit when done, then restart samba with `sudo service smbd restart`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but these steps did not solve the problem. I ran them on 2 of my machines but there was no change at all. I still get the exact same results as I described in the original post.

Comment: The shared home directory might not show in the Network folder, though the previously shared folders should still be there. What do you get if you go to `smb://server/username` in Nautilus, or `\\server\username` in Windows? Generally, you would use one machine for sharing the files and all the others for accessing the files. That's the idea of a file server.

Comment: I need to be able to share both ways.

Comment: Then you should use ssh or vsftp instead of samba.

Comment: I have tried ssh, but I keep getting "permission denied" How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can share between two ubuntu's computers through ssh.
Let's say you want to share the /home folder of your server.

Install ssh by this command in your server.

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

run `ifconfig`  command and write down your ip address eg: 192.168.1.103

test you can loggin in by ssh to the server in the client machine.

```
ssh user@192.168.1.103
```

In the client machine with Ubuntu Desktop go to **file > connect to server**

[image]

then you can complete all fields with your info

[image]

This will be open a nautilus with the folder /home in the server like this.
[image]

In nautilus under the laber Network you will see the server

[image]

You can right click on it and select "Add Bookmark" So you can connect to the ser with one click.