# How can I add "Browse Network" to the files menu in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: menu

Would like to share files between 2 Ubuntu machines on the same local network but there is no Browse Network Option on the Ubuntu 16.04 files menu in the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not particularly worried about encryption as it is within a local network, you can try (assuming you have `python` installed):

```
cd /folder/to/share
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Now, with your other machine, you can access that folder with the local IP of the machine you ran the SimpleHTTPServer on with http://LocalIPHere:8000.

More answers and possible solutions to your problem [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156169/how-do-i-set-up-file-sharing-between-two-ubuntu-laptops-on-my-wireless-network)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the sharing properties of the folders by right clicking the folder and going into the *Sharing* Tab

[image]