# Dummy’s Guide to setting up a LAN with dedicated server on Ubuntu 16.04/18.04

Tags: networking, server, ssh

First off, I have zero experience with networking so forgive me in advance. I am looking to set up several computers to another computer that will act as a dedicated server/central repository for GIT over a LAN with all of the computers connected via ethernet cables using a router. I have all of the computers and the server connected to the router and I assumed that they would all be able to see files in the Public directory in Nautilus once connected, but this is not the case. The router/server are not being used for internet connections, so anything related to that can be disregarded. I am using network manager on all of the computers. The server is running Ubuntu 18.04 and has openssh-server installed on it so that files can be shared via ssh. The clients are all running Ubuntu 16.04. I have the IP addresses for the server and all of the clients.

It doesn’t seem like the client computers are actually connecting to the network. They all come up as “Wired Connection 1” corresponding to eno1 in ifconfig but when I click on them to connect they never do? This is not an issue on the server running Ubuntu 18.04. It says “Wired Connected” and comes up as enp0s31f6 with ifconfig.

In addition, I do not see anything in Nautilus for the clients to connect to the server (e.g. File → Connect to Server doesn’t exist, there is only a “Files” menu). Two links that I have been using (among many) for assistance are here:

[How to make a home server using Ubuntu desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245406/how-to-make-a-home-server-using-ubuntu-desktop)

[How do I set up file sharing between two Ubuntu laptops on my wireless network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156169/how-do-i-set-up-file-sharing-between-two-ubuntu-laptops-on-my-wireless-network)

If anyone might have some pointers I would greatly appreciate it. I feel like I have exhausted the options I’ve come across elsewhere.