# Sharing File between 2 ubuntu machines

Tags: networking, files, sharing, transfer

Sorry for asking what is most probably an already answered question.

I have 2 machines running 12.04 (desktop and a laptop) and I want to move nearly 50gig of files from one to the other in the most efficient way possible.

I have taken all the files I need from my laptop and saved them all inside one file on my desktop, ready to be moved over to my pc. I then plan to move them from my pc, to my external hd (that can only be connected to my desktop pc)

There are a few different ways for me to do this, and I have spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out which would be the best way, but have only succeeded in confusing my little n00b brain more.

I need a guide with basic step by step instructions, including every step that I will need, but also in a format that is easy to understand and implement please.

Im sure this has been answered before, but either I cant find the thread, or my brain is throwing spanners in the works, so your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Ubuntu masters

EDIT I have just tried using 'giver' and it seems to work for small pictures but not for larger things or folders. I used this guide succesfully; [How to transfer files between Ubuntu machines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148970/how-to-transfer-files-between-ubuntu-machines?rq=1) but I assume the programme isnt capable of moving 45gig folders at one time, but it should help someone wanting to move smaller files easily.

Comment: Can't you simply right click on the map containing your files to share and select `local network share` and select `browse network` on the other machine (via the file-browser Nautiles)?

Comment: I have right clicked the folder and clicked sharing options. Then a tick next to 'share this folder' and a tick next to 'guest access' (and/or next to 'allow others to create and delete files in this folder' I have tried all combinations) and that has put the arrow symbol on said file.. Now I go to other pc and click 'home folder' then 'browse network' then I can see the folder but it says unable to mount windows share. Thats as far as I can get

Comment: Could you post the last lines from `cat /var/log/samba/log.yourhostname` here?

Comment: [2014/03/17 12:02:06.916770,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/to keep failed. Permission denied
[2014/03/17 12:02:27.867098,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/to keep failed. Permission denied

Comment: is this what you meant?

Comment: Try to move the folder somewhere outside your user dir, use a short name with no special characters (like spaces) and make sure you give others permission on this folder. Then try to share and browse.

Comment: I have tried changing the name, the permissions are set to allow all to create and delete files, and I can see it on my other pc through 'browse network' but it still says 'unable to mount location' (failed to mount windows share) when i try to open it. I must be doing something wrong :?

Comment: I get the unable to mount error unless i leave both tick boxes empty in the 'sharing options' pop up. If I leave them both empty another pop up appears asking for password for share, yet the password for either machine does nothing?

Comment: Never tried, but maybe this could be useful: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/dukto-lan-file-transfer-tool-is-easy-to.html (note that it's an unsecure tool, but it seems it fits your case)

Comment: Thanks, DUKTO could be exactly what I need, I will report back if I use it

Answer (score 2):

The quickest and easiest way I found to move my files from laptop to pc was DUKTO, recommended to me by https://askubuntu.com/users/16395/rmano Thanks!

The link for DUKTO is here;
http://www.msec.it/blog/?page_id=11

Its simple to set up and use, and I believe its also multi platform. A drawback for some will be the lack of any security features meaning data could be sniffed but that wasn't a problem for me as I just plugged both devices straight into the router and unplugged the phoneline to create a superfast and secure network.

Took less than 2 hours to shift about 110gig of data so Im happy, and would recommend DUKTO :) (for use in a secure network)

Thanks for contributions

P.S. There are a number of other applications claiming to do the same or similar to DUKTO, and they might be even better

Answer (score 0):

If samba does not work, then you should try over ssh:
from terminal install ssh server:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then on the client computer just open nautilus and press CTRL + L and write:

```
sftp://host_username@serverip
```

Then , copy what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I have dl openssh-server as you said, and then typed into terminal of other pc what you said but i replaced host_username with my laptop username, and replaced @serverip with @(my internal ip for the laptop), and then pressed enter and it gives me error (no such filename etc) What am I supposed to be writing here? and can you write a quick example so I can see what you are doing please?

Comment: I have said to open Nautilus file manager, press CTRL+L and so on..
Is it working?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was trying to type that into the terminal *smh* Now I have problem of password not working and/or having a error come up saying could not display/access was denied. This happens whether I use the password for either machine, am I doing something wrong? Thanks for your help so far btw

Comment: If you  are certain that you have entered the right user name / pass combo then I have no idea. Sorry.
on the server( the comp. where you have installed opensshserver) if you write into terminal 'ssh your_user_name@localhost' does it connects?

Answer (score -1):

as I see it you only have one option, that is to plug in the external harddrive to your laptop, ubuntu do got a cloud service but it would take too long for you to move all of it

Comment: sorry I just noticed that you said that the external harddrive only could be used on the desktop, sorry

Comment: Yes that was my first thought but my laptop has no SATA connections for my external HD :/ Thanks for trying though. The only other option I have is to transfer bit by bit using my 8gig card in my phone, lol

Comment: you could split up the files in smaller parts like 1GB and move over the cloud, or if you got a USB stick that would be the fastest way

Comment: Yes that is another possibilty thanks, yet it will still take a while and elbow grease... How is ubuntu for zipping things? Maybe I could zip it down to half its original size then moving it will be quicker at least? I will have a lurk at programmes for ubuntu that are similar to winzip?

Comment: Going off this thread; http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1153693 compressing my folder (which is full of audio and video files) would be pretty pointless, so I wont try that unless advised. Guess I will just have to find the time to copy little by little to my phone memory card, then copy to hd connected to pc. I would like to set up a server on my home network so I can access all my media on my extHD from my various devices ideally. Any links to specific instructions would be nice